# C# - Regular Expression validating Date and Hour

Tags: c#, validation

I receive Date and time from CSV file

```
The received Date format is  YYYYMMDD (string) (there is no ":" ,"-","/" to 
separate  Year month and date).

The received time format is HH:MM (24 Hour clock).
```

I have to validate both so that (example) (i) 000011990 could be invalidated for date (ii) 77:90 could be 
invalidated for time.

The question is ,

Regular expression is the right candidate for do so (or) is there any other way to achieve
it?

Comment: A *three* -digit year? Typo or intentional?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You're looking for [`DateTime.TryParseExact`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms131044.aspx):

```
string source = ...;
DateTime date;
if (!DateTime.TryParseExact(source, 
                            "yyyyMMdd", 
                            CultureInfo.InvariantCulture, 
                            DateTimeStyles.None, 
                            out date)) {
    //Error!
}
```

You can use the same code to validate times, with the format string `"HH:mm"`.

Comment: +1 I'll be darned.... why didn't I ever see that before?? Thanks for pointing that out !!

Answer (score 4):

Your easiest solution would be to use

```
DateTime output;
if(!DateTime.TryParse(yourstring, out output))
{ 
   // string is not a valid DateTime format
}
```

The `DateTime.TryParse` will attempt to convert your string to a DateTime variable, but it won't throw an exception if it fails - rather it return `false` if the string is not recognized as a valid DateTime.

Comment: `ParseExact` might be a better option, though, since the format is known beforehand and `TryParse` (like `Parse`) tries whatever `DateTime` might recognize which may or may not be the right thing to do.

Comment: Well, the question is probably more along the lines of »Is it an error if the date format isn't like previously specified.« Might violate Postel's law, though but in some cases `ParseExact` is probably still better to only accept a single valid representation. (Which imho should always be ISO 8601 but that's probably just my twisted, weird mind :-))

Comment: @Johannes Rössel: or see SLaks' answer - use `TryParseExact` instead of just TryParse....

Answer (score 2):

I think a better way would be to use the date format class built into C#: [DateTime.parse](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/1k1skd40.aspx)

Answer (score 1):

You can use one of the [`TryParse`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.datetime.tryparse.aspx) methods of the `DateTime` struct. They will return false if they fail to parse.

Another option it use the [`ParseExact`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.datetime.parseexact.aspx) methods, but for those you need to specify a format provider.